# Issues with running java (Compiling works but doesn't run)

Tags: java, classpath

I have done ample Google search and read a lot about the issues but still unable to figure it out.

I am trying to run my `SendEmail.java` from command line by specifying the classpath so that it can run from anywhere. I am currently in /Users/{username} folder

When I do

`javac -cp ":/Users/.../src/*:/Users/.../src/lib/jar/*:/Users/.../src/org/*:/Users/.../src/‌​data/*" /Users/.../SendEmail.java`

it compiles and creates the class file.

When I Run it

`java -cp ":/Users/.../src/*:/Users/.../src/lib/jar/*:/Users/.../src/org/*:/Users/.../src/‌​data/*" SendEmail`

it gives an exception mentioned below. Note that when I run it from the same directory: as in do `java SendEmail` in the same directory, it works very well.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /Users/.../SendEmail
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .Users.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.SendEmail

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import java.lang.Readable;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {    

      String to     = "xxxxxxx";                // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String host   = "localhost";
      String from   = "root";
      String pwd    = "root";
      int port      = 25;


      Properties properties = System.getProperties();
              properties.put("mail.transport.protocol","smtp");
              properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
              properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
              properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pwd);
              properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25"); // 587 is the port number of yahoo mail

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);   // Get the default Session object.

      try{


            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);// Create a default MimeMessage object.

             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to)); // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.setSubject("Cohort revenue");// Set Subject: header field

           //  MixpanelDate endingDate = new MixpanelDate();
            // String filename = "data/cohort_" + endingDate + ".txt";
             message.setText(readfile("data/cohort_2013-06-27.txt"));   // Now set the actual message
             Transport.send(message);  // Send message

      } catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }


   public static String readfile (String filename) {
       File file = new File(filename);
       String theString = "";//the final string


       try {

           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

                       while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                           String line = scanner.nextLine();
                           theString = theString + line + "\n";
                       }
                        scanner.close();

                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return theString;

    }

}
```

Comment: add dependent jar files

Comment: Please mention the jar files which you mentioned in Classpath.

Comment: Basically used four files {mail.jar, activation.jar, /{folder in which SendEmail is}/*, /data/*.*}(for the text file). So just two jar files for JavaMail API. As mentioned, it works when I am in the directory and even compiles when I am outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way that you are *running* the compiled Java class.

You are providing a pathname for the class.

What you NEED to provide is the fully qualified class name.  And since the class is declared in the default package ('cos your source code has no `package` statement), that will simply be `SendEmail`.

So ...

```
java -cp ... SendEmail
```

But note that:

- Your current "-cp" option (as per the Question) looks invalid to me.  The components of the classpath should be separated by either colon (":") or semicolon (";") for Linux/Unix/Mac and Windows respectively.  (You have used commas, and those spaces and curly brackets shouldn't be there either!)
- You have to include the directory containing `SendEmail.class` on the classpath.

---

I recommend that you either read the manual entries for the `java` and `javac` commands paying close attention to the command line syntax and the stuff that describes how to set the classpath.

And if you haven't done so already, read the "Getting Started" section of the Java Tutorial which *illustrates* how this stuff works.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. in my -cp option, I have included (1) Folder in which SendEmail class is present as /Users/.../src/*.* (2) jar files and I am running it  FQ class name without any package statement. It still gives the same error

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I have used ":" and have included the directory. NO curly brackets

Comment: Here is the full line:  java -cp ":/Users/.../src/*:/Users/.../src/lib/jar/*:/Users/.../src/org/*:/Users/.../src/data/*" SendEmail

Comment: And what directory is "SendEmail.class" in?  Note ... not "SendEmail.java".

Comment: Here's your problem.  Stars only match JAR files.  Write it like this:  `java -cp "/Users/.../src/:/Users/.../src/lib/jar/*" SendEmail`

Comment: Thanks again Stephen. Do you have a blog or twitter I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

Where did `javac` create the `SendEmail.class` file? In the same folder as your `SendEmail.java` source file? Or in your current folder?

If the latter, leave out the `/Users/...` path in front of `SendEmail` when running.

(If you were expecting the `.class` to be generated in some other place check out the `-d` option to `javac` and the `package` mechanism.)

Comment: javac created the SendEMail.class file in the same folder as SendEmail.java source file and hence, I have to user the entire path

Comment: How about adding that path to the classpath instead? I think `java` expects a class name as last argument, not a path to a filename-without-.java-extension.

Comment: so I added "/.../{folder in which SendEmail is}/*" but it still gives the same issues